# Python push fail to Heroku because of missing "<<<<<HEAD" distribution spec?

Tags: python, heroku, push, flask

I've created a Python application with Flask and right now I'm trying to deploy it on Heroku. When I try to push (using "git push heroku master") I get the following error:

```
raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '<<<<<<< HEAD')

Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:bytefinder.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:bytefinder.git'
```

I'm pretty new to this stuff. My app is working fine on localhost, but this is my initial push to Heroku and I've yet to ever deploy successfully. I should also note, my app uses a database with sqlite3. I understand that databases can only be used in production on Heroku with postgresql (something I realized too late...) and so it might be possible that I am getting some compile time error because of this (although my application compiles fine for when I run it on localhost).

Any advice on the matter would be much appreciated!!

Edit:

Here is the full error!

```
-----> Installing dependencies using pip version 1.1
       Exception:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_16gy6shadhhm2/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
           status = self.run(options, args)
         File "/tmp/build_16gy6shadhhm2/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 219, in run
           for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=option
s):
         File "/tmp/build_16gy6shadhhm2/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1288, in parse_requirements
           req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from)
         File "/tmp/build_16gy6shadhhm2/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 107, in from_line
           return cls(req, comes_from, url=url)
         File "/tmp/build_16gy6shadhhm2/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 40, in __init__
           req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
         File "/tmp/build_16gy6shadhhm2/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2610, in parse
           reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
         File "/tmp/build_16gy6shadhhm2/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2523, in parse_requirements

           raise ValueError("Missing distribution spec", line)
       ValueError: ('Missing distribution spec', '<<<<<<< HEAD')

       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:bytefinder.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:bytefinder.git'
```

Comment: What is "<<<<<<< HEAD"! Sigh.

Comment: Looks like some kind of merge conflict in git may be responsible, although the error is a bit unclear (to me at least). Could you show the offending code lines along with the error?

Comment: Hey Joachim. I've added the full error output. I guess I also need to look a bit more into merging with git, very new to this stuff!

Comment: Unresolved merge conflict in `requirements.txt`, leading to a line being '<<<<<<< HEAD'.